# How to preformat inside textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, pre

I was wondering if it were possible to preformat text that is inside a textarea.  Right now I have a textarea code that I want to add syntax highlighting and also add linenumbers so I am trying to wrap the text inside a pre tag.  Is this correct or should I be doing something completely different?

```
<textarea id="conversation" class="codebox" style="font-family:courier;">
<pre class="brush: js;">//  Start typing...</pre>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this with a textarea. Anything between the `<textarea>` tags is taken literally as text. You'd have to write your own editor, or use a pre-built one, that gives textareas some sort of RTE capability.

Comment: I think you're looking for an in-browser code editor. Try [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textarea`s are not able to render content like you're wanting to do, they only display text. I would suggest an in-browser code editor. A good one is [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/index.html), which is fairly easy to use:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="code" name="code">
// Demo code (the actual new parser character stream implementation)

function StringStream(string) {
  this.pos = 0;
  this.string = string;
}
...
</textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true
});
```

And CodeMirror insert an editable block with that content within the new editor.

There are other options. Wikipedia has a [comparison of *Javascript-based source code editors* entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors).

Answer (score 3):

Having the Pre tag contain the textarea works in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The `textarea` element content is treated as preformatted in implementations, though browsers by default line wrap the text if a line is longer than specified by the `cols` attribute. The wrapping can be disabled using the nonstandard but widely supported attribute `wrap=off`.

The textarea element is not adequate for mere display of content, though. Neither is it suitable for setting up an input editor with formatting features, since all markup inside `textarea` is taken literally.